# Map and Reduce with large datasets = how does it work in practice?

Tags: java, algorithm, mapreduce

i would be thankfull for advice:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce states: "...a large server farm can use MapReduce to sort a petabyte of data in only a few hours..." and "...The master node takes the input, partitions it up into smaller sub-problems, and distributes those to worker nodes..."

I completely do NOT understand how this will work in Practice. Given I have a SAN(storage) with 1 Petabyte of Data. How can I distrubute that amout of data efficiently through the "Master" to the slaves? Thats something I can not understand. Given I have a 10Gibt connection from SAN to the Master, and from the Masters to the slave 1 Gbit, I can at maximum "spread" 10Gbit at a time. How can I process Petabytes withing several hours,as I first have to transfer the data to the "reducer/worker nodes"?

Thanks very much!
Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, on a full-blown Map/Reduce framework, such as [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/), the data storage itself is distributed. Hadoop, for example, has the HDFS distributed file storage system that allows for both redudancy and high performance. The filesystem nodes can be used as computing nodes, or they can be dedicated storage nodes, depending on how to framework has been deployed.

Usually, when mentioning computing times in this case, it is assumed that the input data already exists in the distributed storage of the cluster. The master node merely feeds the computing nodes with data *ranges* to process - not with the data itself.

Comment: hello thkala, thanks for your answer. Just in case you are more deeply informed about hadoops working? do you have any concrete examples how the "workers" then "pull" the data? As far as I undrstand Map/Reduce the standard function takes more or less a "Map" as input. But where is the logic then implemented to actually read the data from the underlaying file system (and feed it into the map). Or do I have to give the master the "unique file ids" and the masters spreads them over the cluster and the workers then use this id to look the data up automatically (as they have the ids)? thanks

Comment: @jens The details of actually fetching the data from the underlying storage are part of the Hadoop framework - it does it for you. All of this is covered in Hadoop docs and getting started guides.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because the master node does the *management*, not the *data transfer*.

The data is stored on a distributed file system and brought in from several nodes simultaneously. (There's no reason for the data to go through the master node.)

Comment: "Partition and distribution" should be read as "decides which node take what part of the data, and sends that node the work order". Data are available from a share FS storage, such as Google Data Storage.